# How can we prevent mobile app crashes if cached data does not align with new reducers structure?

Tags: react-native, caching, mobile-application, offline-caching, redux-persist

I am currently developing an e-commerce management mobile application with React Native, and Redux. We persist data using redux-persist. This brings a great experience with cached data which is a principle in offline-first development.

But there might be a bug that can happen in the mobile world environment.

Let's assume that I have a reducer called "products". That reducer is just an array with product objects. The user logs in and now the data in that reducer is persisted. Later, my development team decides to update the mobile app with a new structure on that "products" reducer. The user's app gets updated, and now the persisted/cached data doesn't align with the new "products" reducer structure which leads to the app crashing.

I may be wrong, but is this an actual bug that can exist? If so, what is a work around or solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a potential bug that can exist i agree because it has happened to me twice and i discovered something which might be helpfull to you. The cause of the crash is dependent on what is stored on disk and what your code uses let me explain.

```
//let say we have a reducer
function ProductReducer(
 state={
       products:[],
       fetching:false
 },action){
   switch(){......}
}


// lets say we have a combine reducer
combineReducers({
   products: ProductReducer
})

//let say we have a component that consums this products
function RenderProducts(){
const {products, fetching} = useSelector((store)=>({
   products: store.products.products,
   fetching: store.products.fetching,
}))
return (
 <View>
  {
    fetching && (
      <Text>
        loading...
      </Text>
      )
   }
     {products.map((item)=>
       <View>
           <Text>
              {item.name}
           </Text>
       </View>)
      }
    </View>
  )
 }
```

**NOW OUR UPDATE LOOKS LIKE THIS**

```
// Now lets new reducer be
function ProductReducer(
state={
    productsList:[],
    fetchingProduct:false
},action){
switch(){......}
}

// Now our Render component becomes
function RenderProducts(){
const {products, fetching} = useSelector((store)=>({
  products: store.products.productsList,
  fetching: store.products.fetchingProduct,
 }))
return (
<View>
 {
   fetching && (
     <Text>
       loading...
     </Text>
     )
 }
 {products.map((item)=>
   <View>
       <Text>
          {item.name}
       </Text>
   </View>)
   }
</View>
```

)
}

Now the second code is going to cause a crash crash for one reason you will be trying to call .map on an undefined object, why is this happening the simple reason is illustrated below

```
// Intial store 
const store = {
  products:{
  products:[], // array of products
  fetching: false,
   }
}
```

**This was our store stored on disk as JSON string
**
AFTER OUR UPDATE TO REDUCER our store remains the same and before we fetch data from our server so that our reducer can write our update to disk the render product component is trying to apply our update and thus the crash

**SOLUTION**

1. You can purge the store // you will not want to this because all stored data including tokens and vital inofrmaton will be lost and user will start app afresh
2. Understanding this problem you can now have several work arounds like dispatching an action to enforce your migration on disk before your components get rendered . this is what i mean
   to apply update i will do this ...

   ```
    function ProductReducer(
       state={
       productsList:[],
       fetchingProduct:false
    },action){
     switch(action.type){
      case 'MIGRATING':{
     if(store.products){ // checking if products exist on the products 
      reducer this will handle updates and new installs
       state = {...state,productsList: 
         state.products,fetchingProduct:state.fetching}

         }
         return state;
       }
     }
    }
   ```

This will write changes to disk but make sure this runs before your components are rendered i will do this for all reducers

3. I will just write my component to always check if a data they are reading is available or else render empty data like '',[],{} for string, array, and object respectively